# Как из Django передать строку, математическое выражение, в JS?

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

Передаю с помощью шаблонизатора Jinja, данные из Django в JavaScript. 
Код выглядит примерно так:

```
a = ['200', '300']
    return render(request, 'OneApp/code1.html', {'test' : a})


var strr2 = []
strr2.push('100')
strr2.push('200')
{% for val in test %}
        strr2.push({{val}})
{% endfor %}
alert(strr2)
```

То вроде как все нормально, Java выводит: "100,200,200,300"
Но если сделать так:

```
a = ['20/0', '300']
```

То вижу что JS произвел вычисления: "100,200,Infinity,300"

Подскажите, как правильно передать строку именно как строку?

Answer (score 0):

Блин, только задал вопрос и сам догадался:( Кавычки надо было поставить...

```
{% for val in test %}
    strr2.push('{{val}}')
{% endfor %}
```